# jQuery Bind each() and also click() on the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following fragment:

```
 $(".server").each(function() {
     var element = $(this);
      //bunch of javascript here with element
 });
```

I also want to bind a single click event for an `id` to do the same work as the above, how is this possible, without copying and pasting the entire block and doing:

```
 $("#my-id").click(function() {
       var element = $(this);
      //bunch of javascript here with element
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the following should work:

```
var eventHandler = function() {
    var element = $(this);
    //bunch of javascript here with element
};

$(".server").each(eventHandler);
$("#my-id").click(eventHandler);
```

Comment: Will the `$(this)` work though in this case if I use an external function?

Comment: I believe it should, simplest way to check would be to give it a try ;)